# What is the difference between virtual photons and real photons?

Tags: photons, virtual-particles

I'm reading a book by Schewe and he describes the electron center as being a swarm of virtual photons. But how are they any different from actual (?) photons?

Comment: possible duplicates: [Virtual photons, what makes them virtual?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68940/84967), [Is there a “difference” between photons that act as virtual particles and photons that act as the quanta of EM radiation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/117013/84967), [What actually are virtual particles?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/286721/84967).

Comment: Quick question:  have you taken any time, any time at all, to search this site on the topic of virtual particles including photons?  If so, would mind referencing those and expanding on that which still puzzles you?

Comment: Don't believe everything your read. Virtual particles don't move in time, real particles do. To exist means to move in time. Thus virtual particles don't exist.