# Quantum entanglement of a particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement

I recently got to know that two particles are entangled and they share information instantly no matter how far they are kept from each other. It is also said that if one particle is kept at one side of the universe and the other particle be kept on the other side of the universe, then also the information sharing will be instant between the two entangled particles. But I am confused that does it violates the theory of special relativity which says that nothing can travel faster than light but in the case of quantum entanglement, the information is transferred instantly. Because I know that light will take billions of years to travel from one side of the universe to the other side(if seen from any other reference frame), but what if we take the reference frame itself of the light? Then the time, taken by the light to travel from one side of the universe to the other one would be zero, isn't it?

If I am wrong please correct me. I really want to know about this, not in a mathematical way but in a simple understandable way as I have not touched the syllabus of quantum entanglement yet but read about it somewhere. Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15282/123208 Entangled particles are certainly *correlated*, but it's misleading to say that information travels from one to the other.

Comment: Thank you the links you have provided cleared everything in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

The particles do not share information. When Alice does her measurement, she has some information about what the result of Bob's measurement would be if he were to perform a measurement, but that information means nothing until later, when she learns the results of Bob's measurement. Likewise, there is no measurement Bob can perform which would tell him anything about Alice's measurement, or even whether Alice has performed a measurement. This is easy to understand if one realises that the wave function is a description of the information known to an observer, and has no other physical meaning.